# Why is the 'Unknown column' warning showing even though the parent table is created?

Tags: mysql

This error keeps showing even though the parent table has been created,

> "#1054 - Unknown column 'B722' in 'field list'".

I followed the following code from the student guide. Please help.

Table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Aircraft_Type`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Aircraft_Type`(
    `AT_ID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `AT_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT AircraftType_pk_ATID PRIMARY KEY (`AT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `Aircraft_Type` (`AT_ID`, `AT_Name`)
VALUES (B722,Boeing 727-200),(B732,Boeing 737-300);
```

Comment: Is this your full query? Can you post the table schema?

Comment: VALUES (`722`,`Boeing 727-200`),(`732`,`Boeing 737-300`); is like VALUES ('722','Boeing 727-200'),('732','Boeing 737-300'). For string we use single quotes `'`

Answer (score 1):

You need single quote for value  and backtics for columns name

```
INSERT INTO `Aircraft_Type` (`AT_ID`, `AT_Name`)
VALUES ('722','Boeing 727-200'),('732','Boeing 737-300');
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not use backticks in MySQL except for table and column names.

You need `VALUES ('722', 'Boeing 727-200'),('732','Boeing 737-300')`

**Pro tip**: SQL code is easier to type, easier to read, and more portable if you avoid using backticks in queries unless your table or column name is a reserved word. For example, your query could be:

```
INSERT INTO Aircraft_Type (AT_ID, AT_Name)
   VALUES ('722','Boeing 727-200'),('732','Boeing 737-300');
```

But a different query with reserved-word tables and columns might have to be:

```
INSERT INTO `group` (`order`, `where`)
   VALUES ('722','Boeing 727-200'),('732','Boeing 737-300');
```

to show those items are actually names, not parts of SQL statements.

**Pro tip**: Avoid using reserved words for column or table names.